# Find most frequent element/row in list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a list of lists of the form:

```
my_list = [[8, [16, 32], [32, 16, 8], 0],
           [16, [16, 32], [32, 16, 8], 0],
           [16, [32, 64], [32, 16, 8], 0],
           [8, [16, 32], [32, 16, 8], 0]]
```

and I would like to extract the most frequent item, namely:

```
most_freq_item = [8, [16, 32], [32, 16, 8], 0]
```

I tried converting the list to numpy and then using np.unique:

```
import numpy as np
list_as_np = np.asarray(my_list)
unq, cnt = np.unique(list_as_np, axis=0, return_counts=True)
```

but this raises `TypeError: The axis argument to unique is not supported for dtype object` because `np.asarray` creates indeed an object and not a proper np.ndarray.

Any suggestions?Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the main issue is the unhashable property of lists, here a possible workaround:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> my_list = [[8, [16, 32], [32, 16, 8], 0],
           [16, [16, 32], [32, 16, 8], 0],
           [16, [32, 64], [32, 16, 8], 0],
           [8, [16, 32], [32, 16, 8], 0]]

>>> l = [sum([[e] if type(e) == int else e for e in s], []) for s in my_list]

>>> l
[[8, 16, 32, 32, 16, 8, 0],
 [16, 16, 32, 32, 16, 8, 0],
 [16, 32, 64, 32, 16, 8, 0],
 [8, 16, 32, 32, 16, 8, 0]]

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(l)

>>> result = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size()
>>> most_freq, cnt = result.idxmax(), result.max()

>>> most_freq
(8, 16, 32, 32, 16, 8, 0) 

>>> cnt
2
```

Answer (score 1):

If the ordering of the list does matter, you could simply transform the sub-list into a string and compare it.

```
from collections import Counter
Counter([str(x) for x in my_list])
# Counter({'[8, [16, 32], [32, 16, 8], 0]': 2,
#         '[16, [16, 32], [32, 16, 8], 0]': 1,
#         '[16, [32, 64], [32, 16, 8], 0]': 1})
```

Of course you can also use your method, either way will get you a string and you can find the list from the string

Answer (score 1):

Ciao Tommi :D

Another option is:

```
import scipy.stats as ss
most_frequent, cnt = ss.mode([str(x) for x in my_list])

most_frequent
array(['[8, [16, 32], [32, 16, 8], 0]'], dtype='<U30')

cnt
array([2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Pandas

```
>>> s = pd.Series(map(str, my_list))
>>> s.value_counts()

[8, [16, 32], [32, 16, 8], 0]     2
[16, [32, 64], [32, 16, 8], 0]    1
[16, [16, 32], [32, 16, 8], 0]    1
```

To get the most frequent element:

```
s.value_counts().index[0]
```

Comment: Hi Andreas!
When trying your solution, I get:
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_func_helper.pxi", line 348, in pandas._libs.hashtable.value_count_object
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_func_helper.pxi", line 359, in pandas._libs.hashtable.value_count_object
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @Tommaso Di Noto I tried it and it works fine. What version of pandas do you have? In any case, you can map the lists to strings: `pd.Series(map(str, my_list))`.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, my pandas version is 0.25.3

Comment: That's weird, I have the same  version and it works. Anyway, I changed my answer (which was actually the initial answer). Does it work now?